# MonoDroid Get Full Image Path, OnActivityResult

Tags: xamarin.android

Using OnActivityResult, how do I get the full path of an image? I am using OnActivityResult and I get get a Bitmap. Can I load that info a file somehow? Here is my code:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case REQUEST_IMAGE:
                    if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
                    {
                        //Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
                        //imagePicture.SetImageBitmap(thumbnail);

                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this to write the image out to a file:

```
var bitmap = (Android.Graphics.Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");

using (var stream = File.Create("/path/to/file"))
{
    bitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
}
```